# Render TextView to TextureView in Android

Tags: android

I have created a video and it is playing in Textureview. Now I want to add one TextView or ImageView like stickers to that TextureView.
For that I have added the ImageView in xml but the ImageView is not recorded into the TextureView. So for that what I need to do to save the ImageView or  TextView with the TextureView.

```
 <com.hw.photomovie.render.GLTextureView
        android:id="@+id/gl_texture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </com.hw.photomovie.render.GLTextureView>

 <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="some text here"/>
```

so when i added this TextView below the GLTextureView  the view is displaying in the output but not save including the GLTextureview i.e., the textview is not visible after saving the video.

Comment: could you please share your code to understand it better

Comment: you have to handle it differently you need to render inside the codec and place on texture view above it problematically